# why I cant use Zipfile in c# windows application?

Tags: c#

I need to read a the file count inside the ZIP file without extracting ZIP file. Below my code and I cannot use ZipFile and I'm getting below error , relevant namespaces also added.

> 'ZipFile': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

```
int count;
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(path))
{
    count = zip.Count;
}
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong.  You can't use the result of `ZipFile.Read(...)` in a using statement because it doesn't implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Because ZipFile class does not implement IDisposable interface. The error says everything.

Comment: What's odd here is that ZipFile doesn't have a `Read()` method.

Comment: There are strong indications that this *isn't your actual code*. E.g. .NET's `ZipFile` class doesn't contain a `Read` method. If you're actually using something like `OpenRead` then you should note that it's return type *isn't* `ZipFile`.

Comment: @dlatikay The compiler reports both errors to me, with the reported error being the first.  I guess the OP neglected to mention the second error.

Comment: you can use ZipArchive,

ZipArchiveEntry,

DeflateStream,

GZipStream

Comment: You say "relevant namespaces also added", so we assume you're talking about `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`, but [that type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.7.2) doesn't have a `static` method named `Read`. Either you aren't posting the correct code, or you're using some other type named `ZipFile`. If it's the second case, please edit the question to indicate which assembly you are referencing to get the `ZipFile` type.

Comment: it could be `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile`, but that one has no static `Read` either. only `Create`. tell us more about references and namespaces used otherwise its guessing.

Comment: @dlatikay I have no idea what kind of class is used by OP. It might be internal OP's class and a fact is - that class is not implementing IDisposable.

Answer (score 2):

The `using` statement allows objects to be automatically disposed of when they go out of scope, and requires objects specified in a `using` statement to implement the `IDisposable` interface, providing the appropriate methods (`Dispose()` etc) to allow that automatic disposal.

More information is available in the [Using documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

As `ZipFile` appears not to implement the `IDisposable` interface, you don't need to use `using`, nor can it be used in a `using` statement - just instantiate it manually:

```
int count;
ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(path);
count = zip.Count;
```

Comment: what is the solution for that?

Comment: [ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have a `Read()` method

Comment: above one cannot use because we cant assign variable as ZipFile zip

Comment: @FakeCaleb That wouldn't cause the `IDisposable` exception specified in the question though. For all we know the OP has build their own `ZipFile` class, or is using one from a different library. If they are using the standard .Net `ZipFile` object, the lack of `Read()` method is an issue to be tackled separately.

Comment: @amila That sounds like a separate issue unrelated to the exception specified in your question, which was related to the unnecessary use of the `using` statement. Perhaps check the documentation of whatever library is providing the ZipFile object for details on its usage?

Answer (score 1):

Try using ziparchive instead and use OpenRead to read path.

```
int count;
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(path))
{
    count = archive.Entries.Count
}
```